# How to avoid showing :id in url when editing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, slug

i am using like

```
def to_param
"#{self.attr1}-#{self.attr2}"
end
```

and my urls look as I want to, though when I :edit,(editing) the url redirects/goes back to showing the :id.

Im letting guest users change some specific record without logging in sending them through a specific link and I want users to not be able to manually change the url or at least show them a large slug so they can't guess the id.

Thanks in advance for any help, theres many posts around this but can't find a solution to fit my needs.

Comment: Have you tried friendly_Id gem?

Comment: I did look at it, but thought wouldn't help, will check it again.

Comment: I am trying friendly_id gem with no luck, if anyone has another suggestion or something to try, let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

credit to @Dipak for pointing me in the right direction.

I managed to do it with Friendly_ID gem, 
though it gave me some trouble because i had some redirects before the actions and it didn't want to pick up the slugs.

I had my redirects as  'redirect_to mymodel_path'

I finally got it working passing 'redirect_to mymodel_path(mymodel)'

Thanks!